# Steam doesn't launch on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS without error message

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, steam

I installed steam on Ubuntu 20.04 from the repositories using

```
sudo apt install steam
```

On running steam the first time, it downloads updates and seems to install them properly, the console output is (after many lines of the form "Downloading update (X of Y)...")

```
[2020-12-26 08:57:53] Downloading update (280,623 of 280,623 KB)...
[2020-12-26 08:57:53] Download Complete.
[2020-12-26 08:57:53] uninstalled manifest found in /home/peter/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2020-12-26 08:57:53] Extracting package...
[2020-12-26 08:58:00] Installing update...
[2020-12-26 08:58:00] Cleaning up...
[2020-12-26 08:58:00] Update complete, launching...
[2020-12-26 08:58:00] Shutdown
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins potentially out-of-date, rebuilding...
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
/home/peter/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam -nominidumps -nobreakpad
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Startup - updater built Dec 20 2020 23:07:02
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] 1. http://client-download.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 100, source = 'baked in'
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] 2. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Verifying installation...
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/peter/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Verification complete
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Downloading update...
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Checking for available updates...
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Downloading manifest: http://client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2020-12-26 08:58:15] Download complete.
[2020-12-26 08:58:15] uninstalled manifest found in /home/peter/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2020-12-26 08:58:15] Extracting package...
[2020-12-26 08:58:21] Installing update...
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] Cleaning up...
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] Update complete, launching Steam...
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] Shutdown
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins potentially out-of-date, rebuilding...
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
/home/peter/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam -nominidumps -nobreakpad
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Startup - updater built Dec 20 2020 23:07:02
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] 1. http://client-download.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 100, source = 'baked in'
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] 2. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Verifying installation...
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/peter/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Verification complete
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Downloading update...
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Checking for available updates...
[2020-12-26 08:58:14] Downloading manifest: http://client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2020-12-26 08:58:15] Download complete.
[2020-12-26 08:58:15] uninstalled manifest found in /home/peter/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2020-12-26 08:58:15] Extracting package...
[2020-12-26 08:58:21] Installing update...
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] Cleaning up...
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] Update complete, launching Steam...
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] Shutdown
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/peter/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
/home/peter/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam -nominidumps -nobreakpad
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] Startup - updater built Dec 20 2020 23:07:02
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] 1. http://client-download.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 100, source = 'baked in'
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] 2. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] Verifying installation...
[2020-12-26 08:58:24] Verification complete
STEAM_RUNTIME_HEAVY: ./steam-runtime-heavy
```

and then it just stops. If I execute steam again by typing

```
steam
```

into the console, I get the output

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
/home/peter/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam -nominidumps -nobreakpad
[2020-12-26 08:58:32] Startup - updater built Dec 20 2020 23:07:02
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2020-12-26 08:58:32] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2020-12-26 08:58:32] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2020-12-26 08:58:32] 1. http://client-download.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 100, source = 'baked in'
[2020-12-26 08:58:32] 2. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2020-12-26 08:58:32] Checking for update on startup
[2020-12-26 08:58:32] Checking for available updates...
[2020-12-26 08:58:32] Downloading manifest: http://client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2020-12-26 08:58:33] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1608507519, installed version 1608507519, downloaded version 0
[2020-12-26 08:58:33] Nothing to do
[2020-12-26 08:58:33] Verifying installation...
[2020-12-26 08:58:33] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2020-12-26 08:58:33] Verification complete
STEAM_RUNTIME_HEAVY: ./steam-runtime-heavy
```

and then it just stops, again.

---

Following another post, I tried the same using

```
sudo apt install steam-installer && sudo apt install steam-devices
```

after purging steam and manually deleting local steam folders, but the output is exactly the same. I'm using a GeForce MX250 with the NVIDIA driver 450, and libnvidia-gl-450:i386 is already installed and at newest version (this seems to have been the problem for some other people).

Comment: Try opening an issue with valve here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues

Comment: Looks like a normal startup.  Do you have a steam icon in the title bar, upper right?  If you click on it does the steam window open?  You may be starting iconized.

Comment: @ubfan1 It appears for about 2 seconds and then disappears. Pretty sure steam just stops running, the console also shows the next input prompt after those 2 seconds (which, to my knowledge, only happens if the program that was started in the console stopped running).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is always the possibility to install the flatpak version of Steam.
Goto https://flathub.org/home and follow the instruction to set up flatpak.
In case you perform all steps, you will be able to search for steam in Software (gnome-software) and install Steam. I have installed with flatpak in Ubuntu, Fedora and now OpenMandriva 4.2. All installations have worked OK, without any performance degradation.